# Apache flink on Kubernetes - Resume job if jobmanager crashes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, high-availability, flink-streaming

I want to run a flink job on kubernetes, using a (persistent) state backend it seems like crashing taskmanagers are no issue as they can ask the jobmanager which checkpoint they need to recover from, if I understand correctly.

A crashing jobmanager seems to be a bit more difficult. On this [flip-6 page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=65147077) I read zookeeper is needed to be able to know what checkpoint the jobmanager needs to use to recover and for leader election.

Seeing as kubernetes will restart the jobmanager whenever it crashes is there a way for the new jobmanager to resume the job without having to setup a zookeeper cluster?

The current solution we are looking at is: when kubernetes wants to kill the jobmanager (because it want to move it to another vm for example) and then create a savepoint, but this would only work for graceful shutdowns.

Edit:
http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Flink-HA-with-Kubernetes-without-Zookeeper-td15033.html seems to be interesting but has no follow-up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Out of the box, Flink requires a ZooKeeper cluster to recover from JobManager crashes. However, I think you can have a lightweight implementation of the `HighAvailabilityServices`, `CompletedCheckpointStore`, `CheckpointIDCounter` and `SubmittedJobGraphStore` which can bring you quite far.

Given that you have only one JobManager running at all times (not entirely sure whether K8s can guarantee this) and that you have a persistent storage location, you could implement a `CompletedCheckpointStore` which retrieves the completed checkpoints from the persistent storage system (e.g. reading all stored checkpoint files). Additionally, you would have a file which contains the current checkpoint id counter for `CheckpointIDCounter` and all the submitted job graphs for the `SubmittedJobGraphStore`. So the basic idea is to store everything on a persistent volume which is accessible by the single JobManager.

Comment: K8s can guarantee a persistent storage location is only mounted in one pod / jobmanager. So that would also guarantee only one jobmanager being alive, this seems promising. If I get this implemented, how can I convince flink to use this HA Service rather than zookeeper?

Comment: You need to implement your own `HighAvailabilityServices` and instantiate Flink with it. The following PR could help you: https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/5530. It allows to provide a custom `HighAvailabilityServices` implementation.

Comment: Any luck with this? Im facing the same situation. Thanks

Comment: @Xeli did you manage to get the custom HighAvailabilityServices working so that jobs get restarted after the Flink cluster on Kubernetes got restarted? I want to achieve the same and would very much appreciate if you would share your code.

Comment: @sceee I did start an lightweight implementation to get this going and it didn't seem too hard. But I never got around to finish it. I've got a new project coming up where I want this so when I do pick it up again I will update this question :)

Comment: @Xeli did you ever managed to finish it?
Thinking of implementing it, but if it's already done would love to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a light version of file-based HA, based on Till's answer and Xeli's partial implementation.
You can find the code in [this github repo](https://github.com/ronlut/flink-k8s) - runs well in production.

Also wrote a blog series explaining how to run a [job cluster on k8s](https://blog.ronlut.com/flink-job-cluster-on-kubernetes/) in general and about this [file-based HA implementation](https://blog.ronlut.com/flink-job-cluster-on-kubernetes-file-based-high-availability/) specifically.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone interested in this, I currently evaluate and implement a similar solution using Kubernetes ConfigMaps and a blob store (e.g. S3) to persist job metadata overlasting JobManager restarts. No need to use local storage as the solution relies on state persisted to blob store.

[Github thmshmm/flink-k8s-ha](https://github.com/thmshmm/flink-k8s-ha)

Still some work to do (persist Checkpoint state) but the basic implementation works quite nice.

If someone likes to use multiple JobManagers, Kubernetes provides an interface to do leader elections which could be leveraged for this.