# Recovery with a single JobManager

Tags: apache-flink

I am attempting to recover my jobs and state when my job manager goes down and I haven't been able to restart my jobs successfully.

From my understanding, TaskManager recovery is aided by the JobManager (this works as expected) and JobManager recovery is completed through Zookeeper.

I am wondering if there is a way to recover the jobmanager without zookeeper?

I am using docker for my setup and all checkpoints & savepoints are persisted to mapped volumes.

Is flink able to recover when all job managers go down? I can afford to wait for the single JobManager to restart.

When I restart the jobmanager I get the following exception: `org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.NotFoundException: Job 446f4392adc32f8e7ba405a474b49e32 not found`

I have set the following in my `flink-conf.yaml`

```
state.backend: filesystem
state.checkpoints.dir: file:///opt/flink/checkpoints
state.savepoints.dir: file:///opt/flink/savepoints
```

I think my issue may that the JAR gets deleted when the job manager is restarted but I am not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, Flink only supports to recover from a `JobManager` fault if you are using ZooKeeper. However, theoretically you can also make it work without it if you can guarantee that there is only a single `JobManager` ever running. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52112538/4815083) for more information.

Comment: Would I be able to use Zookeeper and wait for the single jobmanager to restart? Or would I have to have a standby idling ?

Comment: Having a single `JobManager` which is restarted will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out running your cluster as a "Flink Job Cluster". This will automatically start the job that you baked into the docker image when the container comes up. You can read more [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/docker.html#flink-job-cluster).